# Not able to click on checkBox through selenium webdriver.getting error element not visible

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm adding picture of My DOM and where i want to click(circled). I have used

```
driver.findElement(By.id("itsId")).click()
```

and javascript for clicking on it but it is giving error element not visible.I can see `Unselectable-ON` in `htlm` is it have something to do with clicking? I'm not able to click on any element present on page having unselectale ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("chkObjectAccountsCheckboxAll")));
driver.findElement(By.id("chkObjectAccountsCheckboxAll")).click();
```

this will wait at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable.

Comment: i have used this as well but it is giving error Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//*[@id=\"ext-gen234\"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/span"}

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try to use my selector. If I right undestand you are trying to locate by id, but you are using xPath. Or use xPath method for xPath selector`...By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen234']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/span")...`

Comment: Happy to hear, that your problem solved. Have a nice day!